# urlConnection.connect() works only in AsyncTask - android

Tags: android, connect, urlconnection

I am connecting to a web service using

```
   urlConnection.connect();
```

This works only in AsyncTask. I am not able to execute the above statement on plain activity (without AsyncTask )

Is it the behavior by design, or I am missing something.

By the way, this is my first question

Comment: check out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496278/httpurlconnection-is-throwing-exception

Comment: I am not sure about android, but I know for sure that connecting with Web service must be in separate `threat`. Otherwise you can get blocked `UI` which is runned in the main `threat`

Comment: If you dont't want implement AsyncTask, you should try Volley libary instead, which is easy to learn and helpful. Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow. please use google search and stackoverflow search before posting a question. the chnaces are big, that someone else had already asked your question. [stackoverflow rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Network communications must be done in seprate Thread in android. 
Read more about it here [developer wiki](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid creating an unresponsive UI, don't perform network operations on the UI thread.

You are possibly getting:

```
NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

because you are trying to perform network operation on Main UI Thread and thus overwhelming it. Instead use an `AsyncTask`.

Also, note that if the server is taking much time to respond, the main thread becomes unresponsive too.

Refer [Android Doc for Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting#intro-net-ops) for more information on this.