# Passing a get request to remote server in android

Tags: php, android

I am trying to send a post request to a remote server from an android application. The request should insert values in one of the columns of the database. The PHP code on the server side is like this :

```
 <?php 
$servername="sql9.freesqldatabase.com"; 
$username="sql9193859"; 
$password="MUEpGxKWUt"; 
$dbname="sql9193859"; 
$sms_content=$_GET["sms_content"]; 

$conn=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname); 

// check connection 

if ($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error); 
}
else {
    echo "connected successfully"; 
    $sql="insert into SMS_TABLE(content) values ($sms_content)"; 
    if ($conn->query($sql)===true){
        echo "New record inserted successfully"; 
    }
    else {
        echo "Error:".$sql."<br>".$conn->error; 
    }
}

?>
```

The method to send a get request to the remote server is like this :

```
public void insertSMS() throws IOException {
        viewbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("https://smssaver.000webhostapp.com/helloworld/insert_data.php?sms_content=100");
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

When I type the link on the browser, it is working properly. But, it's not working when I call it in Android.

Comment: Adv : Becarful to **sql injection** , put credentials in a file which its not accessible via web.

Comment: are you sure you wanted to post full DB access, incl. l/p?

Answer (score 1):

[`openConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#openConnection())

> It should be noted that a `URLConnection instance does not establish`
>   `the actual network connection on creation. This will happen only when`
>   `calling URLConnection.connect()`.

You need to call `urlConnection.connect()` to execute your call

```
URL url = new URL("https://smssaver.000webhostapp.com/helloworld/insert_data.php?sms_content=100");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
// additional attributes for request for efficiency 
urlConnection.setReadTimeout(1000);
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

urlConnection.connect();
```

Comment: For a GET request, it should be `setDoOutput(false)`

Comment: Thank you for your response. The application suddenly stops once I click the button and it is still not able to insert the data into the database.

Comment: have you mentioned the internet permissions in manifest please verify it and also post the logcat error details

Comment: Thank you again. I have set internet permission in my manifest as <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> .

Comment: read this https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html and post the result of error filer further edit your post to add more details

Comment: Thanks ! The error is : java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
                                                  at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:730)

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: read and implement this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496278/httpurlconnection-is-throwing-exception and it's happening because you can't executed network calls on main thread